# How can I prevent myself as a developer from seeing user-submitted data on the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, web

I run a website where users submit confidential information. For the sake of example, let's say it's a website for users to store their deepest and darkest secrets.

Protecting this data and keeping it private is important to me. I'm using HTTPS, encrypting the data in the database, have long passwords and two factor authentication on my accounts, etc.

Last week, I was having some production issues and needed to view server log output to see what requests the server was receiving, and generally, what was going on. It's hosted on Heroku which has some tools, like Papertrail, that make it easy to view server logs. The problem is that the web server is receiving user-submitted form input which appears in the server output (as a params hash that was received from the form submission).

So here I am, trying to blur my vision so I don't read someone's private information while trying to track down the problem. Is there any way to obscure this data when it's received by the server?

One of the questions I receive when people hear about the website is, "Well, how do I know you're not just reading my secrets?" The truth is, as far as *I* know, if an admin with access to the server wants to read any of this data, there's really nothing stopping them. I'd like to be able to say, "Nobody can view your secrets. Not even I, ha HA!"

Is this reasonable or even possible?

Note: this is a Ruby on Rails 5 app, hosted on Heroku, using Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think adding something like this to your config would be the first step:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation, :credit_card, :your_secret, ...]
```

Comment: Great! I had no idea that this was a config setting.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that leave the records the same in the database ? Which would mean that you could open your database and see the raw values for credit card, your secret, etc.

Comment: It _sounds_ like `filter_parameters` only affects log output if I'm not mistaken... so encrypting database fields would have to be done separately.

However, even if the fields were encrypted, if you are an admin you could always boot up a local Rails server in the Production environment and decrypt the data.  I asked a long time developer friend, and his input was that this was reasonable. As long as viewing encrypted is a chore and out of sight, I’m happy. Luckily, it sounds like filter_parameters is made just for that.

Comment: yes this filters only the logs, but as i understood the question, db is already encrypted. AND as i said: this would be the "first step"

Comment: It's a good first step, but what's the second step here? I wouldn't consider this solved until both questions in the post are answered.